# Template matching in live videos using opencv python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

do anyone knows how to do template matching in videos(source image is video but template as stored JPG image),can anyone help for this?if any tutorial available for this kindly please share that!!!Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on the opencv website here:

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html

Comment: Thanks!!!This is done for images,but i want to do in videos.can you help me??

Comment: If you want to do it for videos, check out the opencv documentation. They have a lot of examples on how to process videos.

Comment: Thank you Johan.coetzee ,but this is done by using images.I wanted to do in live video